# AWS: Member must satisfy enum value set: [WEB]

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am follow this guide https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/hosting/nextjs/q/platform/js#git-based-deployments to deploy my NextJS application to AWS amplify, but I am running into this error: [image: error] Where and how do I set up the WEB_DYNAMIC value to WEB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same issue today, Check your base directory in Build and test settings, mine was .next which was not correct
So I changed the "scripts" value inside my package.json and then tried.
After making changes my base directory was out and all worked fine.

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next dev",
  "build": "next build && next export",
  "start": "next start"
},
```

See the "scripts" from here
https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/hosting/nextjs/q/platform/js#cli-workflow

Comment: Why they are forcing to have these scripts. Shouldn't we be able to change our scripts according to ours needs?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to export your next build by adding "next export" to your build script like

```json
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next dev",
  "build": "next build && next export",
  "start": "next start"
}
```

Then, change the baseDirectory property in the build settings from .next to out

eg, baseDirectory: out

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue and fixed it by removing "amplify" folder on the project repo. You might have used Amplify CLI to configure the project, it might be messing up with the configuration.